# IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing, reading .shp file. CARTOGRAM

Tags: python, visualization, geospatial, illegalargumentexception, cartogram

I used to run this code from " [https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/gallery/plot_obesity.html"](https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/gallery/plot_obesity.html%22) , with no errors.
but now I get this error when I run it

***"
***IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing
IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing
IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing
IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing
IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing
IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing
IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing
IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing
IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing
IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing
IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing
IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing
IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing
IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing
IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing
IllegalArgumentException: Shell is not a LinearRing
IllegalArgumentException: geometries must not contain null elements
.
.
.
..
.
.
IOPub message rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_msg_rate_limit`.
Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_msg_rate_limit=1000.0 (msgs/s***ec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)"***

seems the problem is with reading the .shp file.

I use this for Visualization of data using cartogram map.
any recommendations how to solve this error, or suggest another way to visualize geospatial data using cartogram.

Comment: You write it worked before, what has changed - code, or you have a new shp file that triggers the error?

Comment: The same shp file is always use

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When i run the notebook i get the error message